# DevExpress WaitForm and PreFilterMessage - unexpected MouseMove messages

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I need the application idle time in my software. For that reason, I made a helper class `ApplicationIdleHelper` which implements the `IMessageFilter` interface.

This works fine and if my application is in idle for some time, I'm showing a `DevExpress WaitForm` using this line of code:

```
SplashScreenManager.ShowForm(typeof(WaitForm));
```

In this `WaitForm` I show the user some information about what's being done in the background. If the user moves the mouse or presses some keys I close the WaitForm like this:

```
SplashScreenManager.CloseForm();
```

**Here's the problem explained in steps:**

1. Mouse cursor is on the form.
2. User doesn't do anything for some time -> idle time -> so I show the `WaitForm`.
3. Now I get a `MouseMove message` in my `PreFilterMessage` method? BUT WHY? Mouse didn't move. No keys pressed? Because I get a `MouseMove message` my application thinks, the user did some input and automatically closes the `WaitForm`.

Same behavior if I close the `WaitForm`.

Here's a sample application, so you should be able to reproduce the behavior:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxabrokJG-OWV3FLV2hNNVk5NjQ/view?usp=sharing

The DevExpress documentation says:

> Wait Forms and Splash Screens are displayed by a Splash Screen Manager
>   in a separate thread.

Maybe this has something to do with that behavior?

Hope somebody can explain me, why I geht a `MouseMove message` in my `PreFilterMessage` function, after showing or closing the `WaitForm`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've encounter this bug before. Save the position of the mouse in first event, if at the next event the position is the same, do nothing. If it have moved, do what you want and update the mouse position

Comment: Thank you very much! Easy solution, but it works fine. Have you also used the WaitForm control or have you encountered the issue with other controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause of this is that the mouse is sensitive to environmental noise.  It's entirely possible for a mouse to experience a little bit of jitter that causes it to report very small movements, which ultimately work out to zero change in position. Alternatively, and this isn't verified, Windows or some other software on the system could be generating extra mouse move messages to make sure that everyone stays in sync with the current mouse position.

Either way, the most stable solution is to decide on an amount of motion you consider "real" (see `threshold` below), and then:

1. Capture the mouse position when you're going to sleep.
2. Every time you get a `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message (or a MouseMove event) calculate the amount of that motion, as in:

   ```
   Point cached; // from when you went to sleep
   Point current; // determined from the window message/event
   double move = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(cached.X - current.X, 2) +
                           Math.Pow(cached.Y - current.Y, 2))

   if (move > threshold)
   {
       // Wake up
   }
   else
   {
       // Ignore and optionally update the cached position 
       // in case the mouse is slowly drifting
   }
   ```

   *(Note that you don't necessarily need to calculate the real distance that way, you could just use ΔX+ΔY)*

Whenever you're dealing with hardware, you need to be ready for it to send you updates that you aren't expecting. Pressing a button for example, can cause the physical contact to bounce, which causes multiple press/break signals at the electrical level. Most of the time, the hardware is designed to filter the noise, but sometimes this seeps through.